# javascript click a button and create an image in a div

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've searched this problem of mine and found some solutions but there is something wrong I must be doing because it doesn't work.
I would like to, simply, just press a button and make an image appear in a certain div. Later, I'd like to add more buttons and each button will correspond to an image changing this image in the same div.

My code is this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    
 </style>    
</head>
<body>
 <button id="button1">Button 1</button><button id="button2">Button 2</button></br>
 <button id="button3">Button 3</button><button id="button4">Button 2</button></br>
 <p> </p>
 
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="2"></div>
 
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("button1").onclick=function() {
   document.getElementById("1").appendChild="<img id="image1" src="img/image1.png" />;
  }
  document.getElementById("button2").onclick=function() {
   document.getElementById("1").appendChild="<img id="image2" src="img/image2.png" />;
  }
  document.getElementById("button3").onclick=function() {
   document.getElementById("2").appendChild="<img id="image3" src="img/image3.png" />;
  }
  document.getElementById("button2").onclick=function() {
   document.getElementById("2").appendChild="<img id="image4" src="img/image4.png" />;
  }
  
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

but somehow I cannot make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using double quotes inside a string encapsulated by double quotes:

```
"<img id="image1" src="img/image1.png" />;
```

This needs to be

```
"<img id=\"image1\" src=\"img/image1.png\" />";
```

Since JavaScript uses quotes (single or double) to set strings you need to escape quotes inside a string with `\` to avoid breaking the string. In your original code JavaScript is parsing the string, finds the end of the string at `id=` and breaks because it expects a line terminator `;` or a `+`.

Look at the highlighting in the first and second code block. It's all red in the second indicating a correct escaped string.

**ALSO**

`appendChild` only works with `nodes/elements` and not with strings. You need `innerHTML`, however that will overwrite the content of your div every time. If you don't want that you could use: [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Example:

```
document.getElementById("1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img id=\"image1\" src=\"img/image1.png\" />");
```

Comment: Is there a double quote missing in the end? Itried with it and without it and is not working. Should I go for innerHTML instead of appendChild?

Comment: @Goncalorsr I've updated my code. That should give you all the information you need. Also hit `F12` on your keyboard in a browser, it will open up the dev tools so you can see the errors your page generates during parsing in the console.

Comment: MOST PERFECT! Thank you Mouser!!

Comment: @Goncalorsr Glad to be of service, please select as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Javascript:
document.getElementById(<img id>).src = "<link to img>";
HTML:
<img id='<img id>' src='<link to img>'>
```